# Filter out responses to a Google Docs form by a failed "check" value in a multi-choice item

Tags: google-forms

I want to lay traps in a Google Docs form to filter respondents. The form has some questions with answers in checkboxes like so:

> Question 1
> ☐ Answer A
> ☐ Answer B
>
> Question 2
> ☐ Answer A
> ☐ Answer B

Some of these checkboxes are traps. That is, if a person chooses one of these, it means that the person answering the question is not adequate/qualified to be considered.

How do I automate the process of excluding such respondents from the summary?